# Select on field Date in OpenEdge

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

I am trying to make a select on the field 'Date' in the table `UVT_DatesOfVersionsBOPos` using the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio `(select * from openquery ([PROALPHA], 'select Date from PAVAR.PUB.UVT_DatesOfVersionsBOPos')`

Unfortunately I get the following error message:

```
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for the connection server "PROALPHA" has the message "[DataDirect] [ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver] [OPENEDGE] Syntax error in SQL statement at or about" Date from PAVAR.PUB.UVT_DatesOfVersionsB "( 10713) ".

Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1

Failed to prepare the select date from PAVAR.PUB.UVT_DatesOfVersionsBOPos query to run for the OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for the linked server "PROALPHA".
```

I assume that SQL interprets the Date field as the Date function and therefore displays an error.
Does anyone of you know the correct syntax so I can get the field?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax error is because of the fact that DATE is a reserved word in OpenEdge SQL. You can use keywords as identifiers in SQL statements only if you delimit them with double quotation marks.

Example 1: This generates syntax error as you described

```
SQLExplorer>select date from pub.cust1;
=== SQL Exception 1 ===
SQLState=HY000
ErrorCode=-210056
[DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Syntax error in SQL statement at or about "date from pub.cust1" (10713)
```

Example 2: This works as we delimit reserved word with double quotes

```
SQLExplorer>select "date" from pub.cust1;
date
----------
```

Link to the documentation: https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dmsrf/openedge-sql-reserved-words.html

Comment: . . Or better advice is to avoid using keywords and reserved words for identifiers.